# SQL windows functions LEAD/LAG but only taking certain values into account?

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto

Let's say you have an app and want to know whether each install can be attributed to a new or returning user.
So you want to check for each ID who installed whether they have a login or register event later, whichever comes earlier.
How would you go from left table to right table?
It would be easy with a window function if I could say:

```
 LAG(event,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER by event_timestamp)
```

+but skip over 'install' events, jump over them

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: added presto, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `lead(ignore nulls)`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(case when event <> 'install' then event end ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by timestamp) as next_event
      from t
     ) t
where event = 'install';
```

The `ignore nulls` option is *standard SQL*.  However, not all databases support it.  There are generally other options in such databases, but without a database tag, standard SQL is the recommendation.

Comment: @Chris . . . Presto should support the `ignore nulls` option.

Comment: could you give an example with it, please? I looked it up, and truly do not understand. So, in the above example, I would want all ID=234 to be shown, I do not want to remove the first 2 instance just because the next event is 'install'. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Chris . . . The next event has nothing to do with the filtering.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff   https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html
lead(IGNORE NULLS case when event <> 'install' then event end)? Sorry, the official presto documentation has no example, and I have never seen this

Comment: @Chris . . . Look at the "value" functions or just search for `ignore nulls`.

Comment: ah thank you so much, this is amazingly useful!